# Database Mail on Amazon RDS / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, database-mail

Since Database Mail is not supported on Amazon RDS with SQL Server, can anyone offer any suggestions on how to send e-mail notifications for failed SQL Server jobs in Amazon RDS?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has posted a detailed blog post based on the way that UnderArmor solves this limitation. It involves a linked SQL Server that you run in EC2 and that EC2 instance is configured to SES to relay the messages through.

[AWS RDS Database Mail](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/powering-up-database-mail-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server-how-under-armour-runs-database-mail-on-amazon-rds-for-sql-server/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

1. Have an EC2 server with SQL Server installed to relay all email notification through Database Mail. Set up as a linked server and call a stored procedure to send the email via SQL Server's Database Mail.
2. Use the Cloud Alert or other 3rd party software for notification of failed jobs.